# extend Ul list in paragraph

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I need UL list to be placed inside the p tag. I have added inside p tag only but it is not exactly starting inside p tag. And also p tag has 1600px of width so I need the li elements to extend beyond that width (I have scroll bar for tat). Now li elements are flowing in multiple lines.

Here is my demo
http://jsfiddle.net/VvuU4/2/

Comment: most of those tags should not be inside a `<p>` tag

Comment: but I cant change the DOM structure now coz it is already implemented completely

Comment: You need to try your best to, it looks like you are trying to use the `p` as a `div`. I'm pretty sure modern browsers will "auto close" that `p` tag before the ul opens, as they assume you missed out the tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately for you, HTML does not allow `ul` (or `div`) to sit inside `p`, so browsers will automatically correct the DOM from this:

```
<p>
    <ul><li>etc</li></ul>
</p>
```

...to look something like this:

```
<p></p>
<ul><li>etc</li></ul>
<p></p>
```

You can verify this using their built-in developer tools. So you'll need to change your markup. Perhaps change the `p` to a `div`?

---

As for the second part of the question, this is a good place to start:

```
ul.list2 {
    width: 500px; /* adjust to suit your needs */
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
ul.list2 li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

It sets the `ul` to use a scrollbar when necessary, and tells inline elements within it not to wrap. It then sets the list items to be inline block items, which makes them sit side by side (like display: inline;) but behave more like block items (i.e. margin, padding, width, height work as you'd expect).

Comment: If I change that p into div, custom scroll bar is not working

Comment: It's not that simple. Not just to change p to div, you must change structure of page. And also css.